# Why isnt my CSS grid responding to my html?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am attempting to use CSS grid (orderForm.css below) however the css styling is not responding to the html that i have written. I have found a lot of times I am not calling the element correctly due to nesting of divs. I was hoping you all could look at my code and tell me what is going on. Some pages it works in visual studios and some pages do not work.

```css
/* Skeleton of pages below */

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

nav#original.navigation,
h1 {
  grid-column: 4 / 10;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Fix the images, not correctly displaying  */

div.blackLogo {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  image-resolution: from-image 300dpi;
}

div.pinkLogo {
  grid-column: 10 / 13;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Footer not responding to grid dimensons */

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* div#all.container {
                grid-column: 1/13 ;
                grid-row: 2/3;
            } */


/* div#name.container, div#billing-address.container,div#mailing-address.container {
                display: inline;
                grid-column: 1 / 7;
                grid-row: 2 / 4; 
            }*/

body>div.grid-container>div#partOne.container {
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}


/* columns not running span of grid-column dimensions */

div#partTwo.container {
  grid-column: 7 / 13;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}


/* div#product-choice.container >h2#product-Choice.heading {
                text-align: center;
            } */


/* div#partTwo.container > div#product-choice.container > h2#product-choice.heading {
            grid-column: 7 / 13;
            grid-row:  2 / 4;
            } */
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <nav class="navigation" id="original">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutUs.html" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="/order.html" target="_blank">Order</a></li>
      <li><a href="/orderForm.html" target="_blank">Order form</a></li>
      <li><a href="/gallery.html" target="_blank">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="name" id="order-form">Order Form</h1>
  <div class="blackLogo">
    <img src="/images/hoodHealerBlack.jpg" alt="Black Hood Healer Logo" width="200" height="80" class="logo" id="Black" />
  </div>

  <div class="pinkLogo">
    <img src="/images/hoodHealerPink.jpg" alt="Pink Hood Healer Logo" width="200" height="80" class="logo" id="Pink" />
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="partOne">
    <div class="container" id="name">
      <h2>Name</h2>
      <label for="Fname">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="Fname" name="first-name" />

      <label for="MInitial">Middle Initial:</label>
      <input type="text" id="MInitial" name="middle-initial" />

      <label for="Lname">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="Lname" name="last-name" />
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="billing-address">
      <h2 class="heading" id="billingAddress">Billing Address</h2>
      <label for="Street-address">Street Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="Street-address" name="StreetAdress" />
      <label for="apartment-PO">Apt # or PO Box:</label>
      <input type="number" id="apartment-PO" name="apartmentPOBox" />
      <!--City, state ; zip code- number; apt number or po box input - number-->
      <br />
      <label for="city">City:</label>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />

      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="state">State</label>
          <select id="state" name="state">
            <option value="---">---</option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
            <option value="District of Columbia">
              District of Columbia
            </option>
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
            <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
            <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
            <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
            <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
            <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
            <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
            <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="Northern Marianas Islands">
              Northern Marianas Islands
            </option>
            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
            <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
            <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
            <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
            <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
            <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
            <option value="Virgin Islands">Virgin Islands</option>
            <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
            <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
          </select>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

      <label for="zip-code">Zip Code:</label>
      <input type="number" id="zip-code" name="zipcode" />

      <input type="checkbox" id="mailing-address" name="mailingaddress" value="Mailing address" />
      <label for="mailing-address">
                Mailing address is the same as billing address.</label
              ><br />
    
              <div class="container" id="mailing_address">
                <h2 class="heading" id="mailingAddress">Mailing Address</h2>
    
                <label for="Street_address">Street Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="Street_address" name="StreetAdress" />

      <label for="apartment_PO">Apartment number or PO Box:</label>
      <input type="number" id="apartment_PO" name="apartmentPOBox" />
      <!--City, state ; zip code- number; apt number or po box input - number-->
      <label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
      <input type="number" id="zip_code" name="zipcode" />

      <label for="City">City:</label>
      <input type="text" id="City" name="city" />

      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="State">State</label>
          <select id="State" name="state">
            <option value="---">---</option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
            <option value="District of Columbia">
              District of Columbia
            </option>
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
            <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
            <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
            <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
            <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
            <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
            <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
            <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="Northern Marianas Islands">
              Northern Marianas Islands
            </option>
            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
            <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
            <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
            <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
            <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
            <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
            <option value="Virgin Islands">Virgin Islands</option>
            <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
            <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
          </select>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contaitner" id="partTwo">
  <div class="container" id="product-choice">
    <h2 class="heading" id="product-Choice">Choose your product:</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="Hat" name="Product" value="HAT" />
      <label for="Hat">Hat</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="Shirt" name="Product" value="SHIRT" />
      <label for="Shirt">Shirt</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="Hoodie" name="Product" value="HOODIE" />
      <label for="Hoodie">Hoodie</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="Pants" name="Product" value="PANTS" />
      <label for="Pants">Pants</label><br />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="size-choice">
    <h2 class="heading" id="size-Choice">Choose your size:</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="Small" name="Size" value="SMALL" />
      <label for="Small">Small</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="Medium" name="Size" value="MEDIUM" />
      <label for="Medium">Medium</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="Large" name="Size" value="LARGE" />
      <label for="Large">Large</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="X-Large" name="Size" value="X-LARGE" />
      <label for="X-Large">X-Large</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="XX-Large" name="Size" value="XX-LARGE" />
      <label for="XX-Large">XX-Large</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="XXX-Large" name="Size" value="XXX-LARGE" />
      <label for="XXX-Large">XXX-Large</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="XXXX-Large" name="Size" value="XXXX-LARGE" />
      <label for="XXXX-Large">XXXX-Large</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="XXXXX-Large" name="Size" value="XXXXX-LARGE" />
      <label for="XXXXX-Large">X-Large</label><br />
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="logo-color">
    <h2 class="heading" id="logo-Color">Choose your style of logo:</h2>

    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="pink" name="logoColor" value="PINK" />
      <label for="pink">Pink</label><br />

      <input type="radio" id="black" name="logoColor" value="BLACK" />
      <label for="black">Black</label><br />
      <!-- <input type="radio" id="Custom" name="logoColor" value="CUSTOM">
                          <label for="Custom">Custom</label> -->
    </form>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>copyright Kajah's Krafts</p>
  <a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>
</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tidy up your code? (Many text editors have a "Code Format" button)

Comment: Im using visual code and do not see such button and i have prettier installed. i do apologize

Comment: Try `Shift + Alt + F` on Windows.

Comment: i am getting an error that states prettier cannot edit the file

Comment: removed ES Lint and Prettier began to work

Answer (score 1):

After going back and double checking my CSS file and the link to the CSS file i found my error. Line 235 container is spelled wrong

Comment: As you debugged your own question and the question was caused by a typo, please remove your question voluntarily! Typo caused issues have no value for the community and will be removed because of this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you aren't seeing your stylings being applied, it is a problem with loading the stylesheets.  Can you ensure that you are including the `link` tag in every page's `head`?

```html
<head>
  <!-- omit -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/orderForm.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Yes, I am including the stylesheet for each page onto each html page

Comment: @kajahMeans Is the css file location right?  You can confirm this by checking the dev tools network tab and seeing if the request for the css file is 200 OK.

Comment: the network tab doesnt show anything

Comment: @kajah Means refresh the page.  if should at least show the html file.  if not, then you have a problem with loading the stylesheet

Comment: i refreshed the page and the css is showing as a 304

Comment: wrong pathing of sources or hyper-reference fall under the same category as `not reproduciable or caused by a type` thos questions hold no value for the SO community and as such should not be answered but commented instead. In case it actually is the reason then also flagged as such for closure and removal.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the link to your style sheet is pointing to the wrong location. /CSS/orderForm.css try removing the / like this "CSS/orderForm.css"

Comment: this is not the case. I have tried to remove "/" and still no luck. Thank you though

Comment: wrong pathing of sources or hyper-reference fall under the same category as `not reproduciable or caused by a type` thos questions hold no value for the SO community and as such should not be answered but commented instead. In case it actually is the reason then also flagged as such for closure and removal.